# Repointing existing workbooks from Oracle to AWS-RDS in Tableau?

Tags: mysql, oracle, amazon-web-services, tableau-api, amazon-rds

I have 70 workbooks where all the worksheets are connected to oracle data source. My team is going to migrate the exact same data on Amazon RDS. So now I want to repoint all the Tableau worksheets to the mysql. Is this possible without recreating anything? If so, is there a way to do it for all the worksheets as opposed to just one at a time? I tried with all the methods mentioned on Jawon Apr 30, 2009 3:16 PM posts:- [Repointing existing workbook to a new datasource](https://community.tableau.com/message/688973#688973) , but nothing worked for me. Is there any way where I can find the mapping of oracle connection for example:- name='oracle.41528.731775173612' in the .twb file to tables and schemas?

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy or pretty but it can be done. It involves hacking the XML of the twb file. These steps give you a general idea and there are ways to streamline the process. Before starting this process, I strongly encourage you to make a backup copy of your twb files. If this goes wrong and you don't have a backup, there's no recovery.

1. Make a copy of your twb file.
2. Open the copy. Create a new data source pointing to the new location. Build out that data source. Save your workbook.
3. Run a diff between the original and new twb files. Look for the connection information that is different.
4. Using a text editor or other program that can make changes to multiple text files, do a search and replace. I use Notepad++ for this. There are plenty of options out there.

Essentially what you are doing is finding what changed in the connection info when you modified the first file. Then you apply that change to all the other files.

Things get complicated if you have schema name changes or any other types of changes to table name or columns. For that reason, it may be advisable to change the files one at a time, opening each one in Tableau to correct any problems as you find them.

Comment: Hi sam, I have already tried the same process. But I am having difficulty in finding out the mapping of the oracle data source with the tables and schemas. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Let me see what I can find. I have both Oracle and MySql sources but have never used anything hosted by Amazon. Is a MySql instance hosted by Amazon any different than one hosted locally or on a different hosting provider?

Comment: Thank you Sam for your prompt response. Yes the MySql instance is hosted by Amazon and the earlier oracle source was from a different oracle server.